# WebDriverException: Message: A new session could not be created

Tags: android, appium

WebDriverException: Message: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver)

I found some solutions but nothing worked

I am new to Automation.

Comment: Add your sample code so that we can understand how your code is working

Comment: I am using robot framework coupled with appium ... there is no code...it is a pseudo language test case..it has so many lines...I can't share all this here..it was working well before ...now only I am facing the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appium is probably shut down or something like there is already a session..so you have to start it again start it from the terminal or command prompt using the command `appium`

P.S:

Run the command `appium-doctor`.It will tell you the problem with set up gone wrong of something like that or see *appium server log* or close all the terminals or command prompts and start with appium-doctor again ..ensure ANDROID_HOME variable like that set correct...

Comment: Let me get it right ! Ok ! Which framework are you using ?

Comment: I am using Robot framework with Appium for Android Automation testing.

Comment: Ok Ok just for clarification

Comment: If you are using windows type appium in the command prompt or if ubuntu or mac terminal. the same way you started the appium very first ..repeat it again..

Comment: I will try and tell you

Comment: Thanks for "Appium doctor"

Comment: I can not comment in question bcuz I do not have 50 points so I comment here to simplifying for you my answer !

Comment: Anyhow the solution I gave basically is check if you have set up correctly once and restart the test environment it is a short cut to solve any problem like this

Comment: .I will check and tell you